# update_attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Необходимо обновить email в профиле пользователя. На данный момент при регистрации указываются общие email от организации или еще откуда либо. Имеется таблица в которой хранятся email, ранее созданные, но так как необходимо обновить контактную информацию.

вьюха

```
=text_field_tag :contact_email, InfoDesk.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).contact_email, class: 'form-control '

= link_to update_email_user_path(@user),method: :post, title: 'Добавить поле для изменения email', class: 'btn btn-primary '
```

контроллер

```
@user=InfoDesk.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
        @user.update_attributes(contact_email: params[:contact_email])
```

В данный момент ошибка возникает, что пытаюсь передать null

PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "contact_email" violates not-null constraint

добавил

миграция создания таблицы

```
  def change
    create_table :info_desks do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, null:false
      t.string :contact_tel, null:false
      t.string :contact_email, null:false
      t.string :private_tel
      t.string :private_email
      t.string :position, null:false
      t.integer :organization_id, null:false
      t.integer :department_id, null:false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Модель огромная. Выкладывать не вариант все.В модели не прописано ничего что связано с данной задачей сейчас, все делается сразу через контроллер. Я не много не могу понять почему передается null.

модель user

```
has_one :info_desk
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :fio, :moderator, :admin, :hospital, :blocks, :encrypted_password, :created_at, :sign_in_count, :updated_at, :role_id,:contact_email, :contact_tel
```

Ну есть в модели метод, который вам даст понятие, как происходит заполнения таблицы

```
def self.add_user params
        new_user = User.create(email: params[:email], username: params[:username], password:"123456", fio:params[:fio], role_id:params[:role_id],  sign_in_count:0)
        InfoDesk.create(user_id:new_user.id, contact_tel: params[:contact_tel], contact_email: params[:email], position: params[:position], organization_id: params[:organization_id], department_id: params[:department_id])
        new_user.roles << Role.find(params[:role_id].to_i)
    end
```

Модель info_desk

```
attr_accessible :contact_email, :contact_tel, :position, :user_id, :organization_id, :department_id, :created_at, :updated_at
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: покажите миграцию которая создает таблицу для модели и модель

Comment: добавил. Посмотрите

Comment: так посмотрите какие параметры приходят в контроллер. и использовать ссылку (link) для обновления данных (post) - это плохая идея.

Comment: да это не только временное решение. в дальнейшем будет оптимизироваться код, пока на скорую руку пишется.  unknown attribute: contact_email    @user =(User.includes(:info_desk)).find(params[:id])   @user.update_attributes(contact_email: params[:contact_email]) выдает, что неопределен атрибут, что может быть не так, атрибуты вроде прописаны,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Адрес не отправляется на сервер, так как разметка этого не предписывает.

Ваше **текстовое поле не является частью формы** и к ссылке* рядом с ней не имеет никакого отношения. При нажатии на эту ссылку* происходит отправка POST без каких бы там ни было значений в полях.

**Сделайте форму**.** В ней обычное поле и обычный сабмит.

---

* На самом деле это не совсем ссылка. *Ссылки не могут совершать запросы методом, отличным от GET.* Это ссылка с JS-обработчиком, который при нажатии на ссылку совершает нужный запрос "синтетически" (собирает пустую форму и отправляет), это не стандартное поведение браузера. И отвечает за этот хак `jquery-ujs` (jQuery unobtrusive JS).

** Есть, конечно, вариант перехвата щелчка через JS и отправка запроса "синтетически" самостоятельно. Но если вы не знали об этом решении ранее, скорее всего сейчас оно вам не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

День добрый. Любые данные отправляются в форме, а у Вас её нет. Форма содержит важную информацию: что слать, куда слать, и каким способом.
Не делайте обращения к базе во вьюхе, вынесите этот вызов в контроллер:

```
@profile = InfoDesk.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

Заметьте, что в форму отдается модель, в которой хранится поле. Форма сама подгрузит значение, если таковое имеется.

Вьюха должна выглядеть как-то так (в случае .erb)

```
<%= form_for @profile do |profile| %>
  <%= profile.text_field :contact_email %>
  <%= profile.submit %>
<% end %>
```