# Submit по нажатию на Link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Есть форма которая должна записывать новую строчку таблицы по нажатию на ссылку  link_to или кнопку t.submit.

```
<%= form_for([@projectlast, @projectlast.todos.build], id: "form-id") do |t| %>
<p>
<%= t.text_area :text %> 
</p>
<%= link_to 'Отмена' %>
<%= t.submit %>
<%= link_to 'Ок', projects_path, class:"submit-btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Есть файл applicatiion.js

```
ready = ->
  if $("#form-id").length > 0
    $(".submit-btn").click (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      $("#form-id").submit()

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему когда нажимаешь на кнопку в таблицу новая строчка добавляется, а при нажатии на link_to нет.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [update_attributes rails](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/656620/181100).

Comment: Можете показать пример как это сделать синтетически через js?

Comment: Можете посмотреть, как это делает сам Rails, если указать атрибут `method`: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L210-L229